# HTML Parsing and erronous \xa0

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am a beginner in the world of coding and tried to do some HTML scraping. I already was succesful in some earlier projects, but my current project is not working.

The problem has to do with this site:
http://console.worldoftanks.com/encyclopedia/vehicles/usa/T1_Cunningham/
I would like to extract the data from this site (and similar ones).

However, when I try to extract data such as tier, price etc. I run into a problem. My code is as follows:

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import lxml
import urllib2
from pprint import pprint
##

site="http://console.worldoftanks.com/encyclopedia/vehicles/usa/T1_Cunningham/"     
page=urllib2.urlopen(site)
soup= BS(page.read(),"lxml")

tank_tier = soup.findAll('span', {'data-class':"tank.tier"})
tier= tank_tier[0].contents
print "Tier is:", tier

main_stats= soup.findAll('div', {'class':"main-stats_item"})
print "\n\n Main stats:"
pprint(main_stats)
```

---

The problem with this code is that the data is somehow lost. The result of this code is as follows:

```
Tier is: [u'\xa0']

 Main stats:
[<div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/flags/usa.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.nation">\xa0</span>\n</span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Nation</span>\n</div>,
 <div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/vehicle-types/lighttank.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.type">\xa0</span>\n</span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Type</span>\n</div>,
 <div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/configuration/tier.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.tier">\xa0</span>\n</span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Tier</span>\n</div>,
 <div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/currency/gold.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.price">\xa0</span>\n</span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Cost</span>\n<span class="main-stats_price">(Silver)</span>\n</div>,
 <div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/configuration/weight.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.weight">\xa0</span> / <span data-class="tank.loadLimit">\xa0</span>t\n                    </span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Weight / Load limit</span>\n</div>,
 <div class="main-stats_item">\n<span class="main-stats_title">\n<span class="main-stats_ico">\n<span class="svg-icon svg-icon__config js-svg-icon" data-src="//wxpcdn.gcdn.co/static/87ceef6/portal/img/svg-icons/configuration/hit-points.svg"></span>\n</span>\n<span data-class="tank.hitPoints">\xa0</span>\n</span>\n<span class="main-stats_note">Hit Points</span>\n</div>]
```

So first, when I try to find some specific value (like Tier) it turns the data into \xa0 which is a nonbreaking space character. If I look for the other data (the other, longer part of the result), one can see that all the data under main-stats_item becomes \xa0 instead of the actual values.

I tried multiple things from using encode('utf-8') to using the lxml library to create a tree.xpath. Using the tree also results in the \xa0 character.

Does anyone know why the data is replaced with these non breaking space characters? And possibly how to solve it? Note that I'm not trying to remove the \xa0, I'm trying to get the data that is supposed to be in that spot.

I am using Python 2.7

Hopefully someone can help a beginner take some more steps into the world of coding.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not "lost".

The problem is that the code is dynamically created with javascript so you need a browser-like experience to emulate the javascript actions.

You would have to use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) preferably with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) as a headless browser!

You can also use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) but it's not as common, there is more support for selenium users.

Comment: Thanks that works! I am now able to see the data in the soup. I still need to figure out a way how to click the different buttons in an attempt to get all the different data, but this is a good start. Thanks again for the quick reply!

Comment: @Dennis please accept the answer if I was of any help :)

Comment: @Dennis, you don't need bs4 at all if you are using selenium, you can use xpaths and selects to parse the source.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham He doesn't need but it's a nice to have, lot's of people choose to have it because it's simpler to navigate the nodes

Comment: I accepted the answer @RafaelAlmeida. I forgot to, so thanks for the heads up. I think I will try to work it out with bs4 first, since I have some experience with it, but also in selenium just to get some experience. Thanks for the idea PadraicCunningham